# Time and work. Arithmetic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> 3 cooks have to make 80 burgers.They are known to make 20 pieces every
>   minute working together.The 1st cook began working alone and made 20
>   pieces having worked for sometime more than 3 mins.The remaining part
>   of the work was done by second and 3rd cook working together.It took a
>   total of 8 minutes to complete the 80 burgers.How many minutes would
>   it take the 1st cook alone to cook 160 burgers?

Let the rate at which the three cooks A,B,C prepare burgers be a burgers/min, b  burgers/min, c  burgers/min.

Therefore ATQ:

$$a+b+c= 20 \tag{1}$$

Let the amount of time in which the first cook A worked alone be t.

This implies:

$$at=20 \tag{2}$$

also:

$$at+(b+c)(8-t)=80$$

This implies:

$$20+(b+c)(8-\frac{20}{a})=80 \tag{3}$$

So I have two equations (1) and (3) involving the variables a,b and c.

I can't form the third equation.

And also, how to solve the equations wherein variable 'a' in eq 3 looks so scary!

Comment: Do you have the answer in your book? What does it say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_{1}$ be rate of work of the first cook (burgers per minute)
Let $x_{2}$ be rate of work of the first cook (burgers per minute)
Let $x_{3}$ be rate of work of the first cook (burgers per minute)
And let $t$ be the time (measured in minutes) it takes the first cook to make $20$ burgers

These are our conditions expressed in mathematical form:

$$
x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=20 \text{ (when they work together)}\\
t\cdot x_{1}=20 \text{ (first cook makes 20 burgers)}\\
(8-t)(x_{2}+x_{3})=60 \text{ (rest of work done by 2nd and 3rd cooks)}\\
t\cdot x_{1}+(8-t)(x_{2}+x_{3})=80 \text{ (8 minutes to complete the job)}
$$

Solution:

$$
x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=20\implies x_{2}+x_{3}=20-x_{1}\\
\text{therefore}\\
t\cdot x_{1}+(8-t)(20-x_{1})=80
$$
Rate of work of the first cook:

$$
t\cdot x_{1}+(8-t)(20-x_{1})=80\implies x_{1}=\frac{t10-40}{t-4}
$$

Now, solve for $t$:

$$
t\cdot \left(\frac{t10-40}{t-4}\right)=20\implies t=2 \text{ and } t=4\\
$$

$t=4$ is the only solution of this equation that makes sense here because according to one of the problem's statements, the time it takes the first cook to make $20$ burgers is more than $3$ minutes (and $t=4 \text{ minutes}$ is that three and a little bit minutes it takes him to make $20$ burgers).

The rate of work of the first cook therefore:

$$
t\cdot x_{1}=20\implies\\\
x_{1}=\frac{20 \text{ burgers}}{4 \text{ minutes}}\implies\\
x_{1}=5 \text{ burgers / minute}
$$

For the first cook to make $160$ burgers, we have to solve this simple equation where $M$ is how many minutes it will take him to do this job:
$$
M\cdot x_{1}=160\\
M=\frac{160}{x_{1}}\\
M=\frac{160 \text{ burgers}}{5 \text{ burgers / minute}}\\
M=32 \text{ minutes}
$$
Answer: it will take the first cook $32$ minutes to make $160$ burgers.

Comment: Hi, the answer is 32 minutes. Your approach is correct. Taking hints from your answer I solved the problem.Thanks. It just has some calculation mistake. Please don't delete the first 6 lines of equation in case you edit the solution. If you edit the solution, I am marking your answer as the solution.

Comment: Sure. I'll double check everything again later. I think I just made a simple calculation mistake somewhere.

Comment: Done with the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Let the time required to cook $160$ burgers by the first cook be $T.$ This gives $a = \frac{160}{T}$. Then, the time required to cook twenty burgers equals: $$\frac{20}{\frac{160}{T}}=\frac{T}{8}$$

This gives us: $$b+c = \frac{80-20}{8-\frac{T}{8}}=\frac{480}{64-T}$$

Now, as $a+b+c=20$, we have the quadratic equation: $$512-48T+T^2=0 \implies T= 16, 32$$

As, $\frac{T}{8}>3$, we choose the **solution $T=32$**.

Answer (score 2):

Cooks 1, 2 and 3.

Respective speeds: $a,b,c$.

First part (1st cook) : $(3+x) \times a=20$.

Second part (2nd and 3rd cooks working together) : $b \times (8-(3+x)) + c \times (8-(3+x))=60$. I.e. $b+c= \dfrac {60} { 5-x}$.

We know that : $a+b+c=20$ and thus: $b+c= 20-a$.

So:

> $a= 20- \dfrac {60} { 5-x}$.

Substituting $a$ in the first equation and simplifying, we get:

> > $x^2-1=0$.

We need the solution $x=1$, that means that the time the 1st cook worked alone is $4$ minutes. This implies: $a=\dfrac {20} {4} =5$.

Conclusion: How many minutes would it take the 1st cook alone to cook $160$ burgers?

Comment: Sir, is there any way by which we can find the number of days b or c will take to complete the work?

Comment: @Soumee - we have $a+(b+c)=20$ and thus: $b+c=15$. And this fit with the fact that they produced **togetehr** $60$ burger in $4$ minutes. But it seems to me that we have no further info to "split" the total speed between the two.

Comment: Right sir...Thank you....

Comment: Sir can you please help me with this question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2567879/394202